# Determine available disk size with a sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, disk, diskspace

I need to determine the available space on the drive where my database lives.
I know about the `xp_fixeddrives` procedure but how do I get the info for the specific drive where my database resides?

Comment: The database choice is under my control so will be SQL Server 2005 or later.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Something like this?

```
declare @DatabaseName sysname 
set @DatabaseName = 'master'

declare @Drive table(DriveName char, FreeSpaceInMegabytes int)
insert @Drive execute xp_fixeddrives

select 
    mas.type_desc FileType, 
    mas.name FileName, 
    mas.physical_name PhysicalFileName, 
    mas.size * 8 / 1024 FileSizeInMegabytes,
    drv.DriveName, 
    drv.FreeSpaceInMegabytes
from sys.master_files mas
    left join @Drive drv on
        left(mas.physical_name, 1) = drv.DriveName
where database_id = db_id(@DatabaseName)
```

Set `@DatabaseName` accordingly.

Answer (score 8):

```
    SELECT Drive
    ,   TotalSpaceGB
    ,   FreeSpaceGB
    ,   PctFree
    ,   PctFreeExact
    FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT
        SUBSTRING(dovs.volume_mount_point, 1, 10) AS Drive
    ,   CONVERT(INT, dovs.total_bytes / 1024.0 / 1024.0 / 1024.0) AS TotalSpaceGB
    ,   CONVERT(INT, dovs.available_bytes / 1048576.0) / 1024 AS FreeSpaceGB
    ,   CAST(ROUND(( CONVERT(FLOAT, dovs.available_bytes / 1048576.0) / CONVERT(FLOAT, dovs.total_bytes / 1024.0 /
                         1024.0) * 100 ), 2) AS NVARCHAR(50)) + '%' AS PctFree
    ,   CONVERT(FLOAT, dovs.available_bytes / 1048576.0) / CONVERT(FLOAT, dovs.total_bytes / 1024.0 / 1024.0) * 100 AS PctFreeExact                
    FROM    sys.master_files AS mf
    CROSS APPLY sys.dm_os_volume_stats(mf.database_id, mf.file_id) AS dovs) AS DE
```

Comment: Consider adding information on your steps to solve this.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't mentioned your version of SQL Server. Starting with SQL Server 2005 you can get plenty of information from sys.database_files and relate that to the output of xp_fixeddrives.